# Как работать с MSSQL из PHP PDO

Tags: php, linux, sql-server, pdo, администрирование

PHP 5.6.24 (ОС Debian 8). Нужен драйвер для PDO для работы с MSSQL phpinfo() пишет что сейчас есть драйверы только для mysql, sqlite.

Вопрос: как установить драйвер? В целом имею представление что нужно скачать какой-то файл, куда-то кинуть и подключить его в php.ini но как конкретно это сделать?

Видел драйвер здесь https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql но там пишут PHP 7, для версии 5.6 подойдёт или нужен другой?

В php.ini в разделе PDO сейчас такие строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://bfy.tw/Aupd А вообще посмотрте в extensions, может драйвер уже установлен. Или apt-get install php5-mssql

Comment: @ilyaplot я гуглил там куча разных методов и видов драйевров, например есть odbc. Вот мне нужен odbc или не odbc?

Comment: `does not provide backwards compatibility with PHP 5.` не подойдет по ссылке для 5го

Comment: Придется вам помучиться. Начните с этого http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953882/connecting-to-mssql-using-pdo-through-php-and-linux

Answer (score 0):

1. Поместить файл с библиотекой в директорию ext или ту, которая указана в php.ini, параметр extension_dir
2. в php.ini добавить строку чтобы активировать библиотеку: 
   параметр extension=*название файла библиотеки*
3. Перезапустить apache